# WinForms - Activity Indicator

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, controls

In a WinForms application, I want to provide visual feedback that a looping background procedure is ongoing (It isn't something that is initiated by the user or blocks them from using the UI)

**Edit** - It is going on all the time, looped. The user doesn't need to know when an iteration starts or finishes.

I'm thinking some kind of small, square, looping animation. Something like the segmented "spinner" often used in Mac/iPhone applications.

[spinner http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/4402/spinner.png](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/4402/spinner.png)

Is there a built-in WinForms control that is a similar idea? If not, what's the best way to go about this?

Comment: What about using the Wait cursor?

Comment: Can that animation be placed on the form? It will be in this state virtually all the time (it's essentially confirmation that the user is being shown live/auto-refreshed data), so I don't want to change the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just drop an [animated GIF](http://ajaxload.info/) on form and make sure you're not blocking the UI thread:

[image]

Comment: You could even hide/show the animated gif using a delegate in the background process when said process is running...this seems the simplest solution

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing this

```
public void DoWork()
{
  try
  {
     this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
     DoSomeBigThing();
     . . . .
  }
  catch()
  {
      . . . ..
  }
  finally
  {
      . . . .
      this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
  }
}
```

1. Create your own mouse cursor (.cur file) with some free tools (Google or Bing for that)
2. Use [AutoWaitCursor](https://github.com/rluiten/WinForm-AutoWaitCursor-Problem/blob/master/WinForm%20AutoWaitCursor%20Problem/AutoWaitCursor.cs) and set your mouse cursor to your own created cursor

   Cursor myCursor = new Cursor("myCoolCursor.cur");

Comment: https://github.com/rluiten/WinForm-AutoWaitCursor-Problem/blob/master/WinForm%20AutoWaitCursor%20Problem/AutoWaitCursor.cs

Answer (score 1):

Use either a custom developed threading model, or the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Let the background thread periodically post events back to your main GUI thread using a delegate handler, take thread safety into account, or using the [ProgressChanged](http://p3net.mvps.org/Topics/WinForms/BackgroundWorker.aspx) event if you are using the BackgroundWorker.